# $dT/dx=0$ always true?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

**Disclaimer**:

I am posting it here because I am searching for mathematical arguments supporting the validity of the given differential equation

---

In a Classical Mechanics book I found the assumption that for an arbitrary particle with constant mass in the Real line $dT/dx=0$, with $T$ the Kinetic Energy i.e. $T=(m⋅\dot x^2)/2$

My hypothesis is that the author used the following 'identity'
$$d\dot x^2/dx=0$$

But solving the differential equation (correct me if I am wrong please) I get to $\dot x=f(t)$

Which I think could be wrong because it could be $\dot x=f(x,t)$ couldn't it?

Comment: In Lagrangian mechanics, the position and velocity variables are taken to be independent of each other.

Comment: Cameron's (correct) comment means that this is really $\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}$, where $\dot{x}$ is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @Ian!

Comment: I think the comments are not really relevant to the question. The question specified $dT/dx$, but not a partial derivative.

Comment: $\frac{dT}{dx}$ only makes sense if you have specified the way that everything changes as a function of $x$, which is a rather weird thing to do in classical mechanics. You could try to speak of $\frac{dt}{dx}$ even though that's generally only locally defined and then use the chain rule, like in your answer, but it seems unlikely that this is what is happening in the OP's source.

Comment: @Ian It may seem to have no physical meaning, but it actually has a significant physical meaning: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskPhysics/comments/5i1b1n/physics_1_proof_of_f_dkdx_k_is_kinetic_energy/.

Comment: @Hermis14 Fair point, I guess it's less weird to do than I thought, but that's probably not what's going on in the OP unless the point is that they are dealing with a system with no force. It being $\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}$ with fixed $\dot{x}$ seems much more likely to me, especially since the letter $T$ was used (an unusual notation IME, except in the context of Lagrangian mechanics). In any case a total derivative of a multivariate quantity with respect to some variable *does* only make sense once you have specified how all relevant quantities depend on that variable.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it is not always true. As you supposed, let $\dot{x} = f(t,x)$ with $x(0) = x_0$. Then,
$$
\dfrac{dT}{dx}(t,x)= \dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t} \dfrac{dt}{dx}+\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial x}
$$
which is not guaranteed to be identically zero. Think of a situation where a mass traverses the floor while losing its kinetic energy. Clearly in this case, $dT/dx \neq 0$.

Furthermore, as you know, the solution of ODE is always a function of only $t$. But the time $t$ can also be expressed as a function of $x$ (i.e., the inverse of $x(t)$) for some restricted domain on which $x$ is injective. Probably, you are confused concerning the partial derivative and total derivative.